# Indexing of elements in a Seq of string with chisel

Tags: chisel

I have, tab=Array(1.U, 6.U, 5.U, 2.U, 4.U, 3.U) and Y=Seq(b,g,g,g,b,g), tab is an array of UInt.
I want to do a map on tab as follows:

```
tab.map(case idx=>Y(idx))
```

But I keep getting the **error: found chisel3.core.UInt, required Int.**
I tried using the function **peek()** to convert idx to an Int by doing

```
tab.map(case idx=>Y(peek(idx).toInt)
```

but I get peek not found. I also saw that I cannot convert a chisel UInt to an Int [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/chisel-users/o0wO0mPVG9o/YwR1qoh2BUoJ) but did not understand the use of peek well with the example given. So please, is there another approach to do the above? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you cannot access the elements of scala collections using a hardware construct like UInt or SInt.  It should work if you wrap Y in a Vec.  Depending on your overall module this would probably look like

```
val YVec = VecInit(Y)
val mappedY = tab.map { case idx => YVec(idx) }
```

Comment: It seems that this does not apply to Sequence of strings.I get the error VecInit() cannot be applied to (Seq[String])

Comment: Yes, you cannot VecInit strings, but if your values are alphabetic you should be able to represent them as an 8 or 16 bit UInts.  If you want to do full strings you would have to make Vec of Vecs where the inner Vec's are strings.  A lot more hardware to manage all that.